# How do I use cgiscripts to run opencv python functions directly on a django webpage?

Tags: python, html, django, opencv

I've been looking for a way to directly execute python functions in and I came across cgiscripts but reading through it it only goes into detail about retrieving information from the python function. My first question is is it possible to use cgi scripts for a python function that uses opencv to play a video and process it in Django? If it can, what is the best way to do it so that I can display the video directly on a Django webpage? Thanks in advance.
Couple of notes: I already know how to get the python function to execute via a button click so I have some knowledge of the process of calling a python function.

Comment: I can't understand why you want to use CGI if you're already using Django. Those are alternative technologies for running a web page; there's no reason to combine them.

Comment: oh ok, are there any specific ways I can do this with django that will allow me to run it directly on the webpage without any buttons?